# Looking for a way to highlight 2 characters before and 2 characters after all tracked changes

Tags: microsoft-word, characters

I am using a code that allows me to automatically convert all tracked changes to highlighted text. However, when the track change is a suppression, there is of course no highlight after I "Accept All Modifications". Therefore, I am looking for a code that would allow me to highlight **2 characters before** and **2 characters after** all tracked changes. Then, after accepting all modifications, I would be able to visualize where suppressions have been made.

Here is my code:

```
Sub tracked_to_highlighted()           
    tempState = ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions
    ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False    
    For Each Change In ActiveDocument.Revisions        
        Set myRange = Change.Range
        myRange.Revisions.AcceptAll
        myRange.HighlightColorIndex = wdGreen            
    Next    
    ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = tempState
End Sub
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
Sub tracked_to_highlighted()
    Dim myRange As word.Range
    tempState = ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions
    ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False
    For Each Change In ActiveDocument.Revisions
        Set myRange = Change.Range
        myRange.MoveStart word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, Count:=-2
        myRange.MoveEnd word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, Count:=2
        myRange.HighlightColorIndex = wdGreen
        myRange.Revisions.AcceptAll
    Next
    ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = tempState
End Sub
```